# Freeze a pushbutton by toggling a toggle switch

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2

I have a created QPushButton which should freeze when I toggle the toggle switch.

Below is the code for the push button

```py
class Ui_MainWindow(QObject):
    def setBP(self):
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", psutil.sensors_battery().percent)
 
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        MainWindow.showMaximized()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1920, 1080))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.tab)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton= QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab,  #ADDING BUTTON
                                                  checkable=True, toggled=self.release)    
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(960, 620, 241, 71))    
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("MS Sans Serif")
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(
            "background-color: rgb(27, 200, 108);color: rgb(255,255,255)")                                        
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def release(self):
        a = self.lcdNumber.value()
        self.lcdNumber_2.display(a)
        self.pushButton.setDisabled(True)
```

For the toggle switch, I created a class

```py
class ToggleSwitch(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        #app = QApplication([])
        tog = QHBoxLayout()
        secondaryToggle = AnimatedToggle(
            checked_color="#00AA00",
 
        )
        tog.addWidget(secondaryToggle)
        self.setLayout(tog)
```

Here is a small gif demo to show to the what I wanted:

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, I have added some more code.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you asking? What is the relation between the two codes? Besides that, consider that trying to modify files created with pyuic (or mimic their behavior) is considered bad practice. Please rebuild the files from the UI and use them as they're supposed to be (only by importing them and implementing the logic in another script) as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).